# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I encounter `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')` when trying to display Post.vue component. The problem seems to appear at the use of `const { loading, data, error } = useQuery...`. How can I resolve this? I appreciate your explanation.

Post.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-if="post" class="post">
    <h2>{{ post.title }}: {{ post.subtitle }}</h2>
    By <AuthorLink :author="post.author" />
    <div>{{ displayableDate(post.publishDate) }}</div>
    <p class="post__description">{{ post.metaDescription }}</p>
    <article>
      {{ post.body }}
    </article>
    <ul>
      <li class="post__tags" v-for="tag in post.tags" :key="tag.name">
        <router-link :to="`/tag/${tag.name}`">#{{ tag.name }}</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    Loading...
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import apolloClient from '@/apollo-client';
import AuthorLink from '@/components/AuthorLink.vue';

const slug = ref(null);
const router = useRouter();

const updateSlug = () => {
  const params = router.currentRoute.value.params;
  if (params.slug !== undefined) {
    slug.value = params.slug;
  }
};

updateSlug(); // Initial call to update slug

router.afterEach(() => {
  updateSlug(); // Call updateSlug whenever route changes
});

const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(gql`
  query PostBySlug($slug: String!) {
    postBySlug(slug: $slug) {
      title
      subtitle
      publishDate
      metaDescription
      slug
      body
      author {
        user {
          username
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
      tags {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`, {
  variables: {
    slug: slug.value || '',
  },
  client: apolloClient,
});

const post = computed(() => data?.postBySlug);

function displayableDate(date) {
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'full' }).format(new Date(date));
}
</script>
```